# Array in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I created a function that read data from a mysql db.

I want to put the data into a array and read that outside of the PHP function.

```
function showCategory($con) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM kategorien";
    $kategorien = array();     

    $result = $con->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $kategorien[] = $row["kategorie"];
        return $kategorien;
    }   
}
```

To load the data outside from function:

```
$kategorien = showCategory($con);
echo $kategorien['kategorie'][0];
```

It doesn't work. Whats wrong?

Comment: First try return $kategorien; outside the While loop because return naturally ends execution of the current function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
return $kategorien;
```

will exit the loop and the function, so move this to the end of the function and not in the loop.

```
function showCategory($con) {
    $sql = "SELECT kategorie FROM kategorien";
    $kategorien = array();     

    $result = $con->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $kategorien[] = $row["kategorie"];
    }   
    return $kategorien;
}
```

Rather than using *, it's also worth specifying the column names if you only need some of them.

Display the data using...

```
$kategorien = showCategory($con);
print_r( $kategorien );
```

or use a `foreach()`...

```
$kategorien = showCategory($con);
foreach ( $kategorien as $kat ) {
    echo $kat.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But i'm only get only the first entry ... $kategorien = showCategory($con);
echo $kategorien[0];

Comment: Try `print_r($kategorien)` instead the `echo`

Comment: @NigelRen you can do `array_column` as `return array_column($result, 'kategorie');` and not use the while loop (if used `fetch_assoc_all`)

Comment: I've added a few more options to display the data - but `$kategorien[0]` is only the first element of the array (`[0]`)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead, because returning $kategorien will exit the loop, so it will only run once.

```
function showCategory($con) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM kategorien";
    $kategorien = array();     

        $result = $con->query($sql);
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
               $kategorien[] = $row["kategorie"];
            }  
            return $kategorien;
}
```